# PreferenceScreen inside ViewPager not scrolling properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-preferences

Hey guys I have an Coordinator layout inside which  i have some tabs and a viewpager which displays my preferencefragment. You can have a look here:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/TabStyle">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:theme="@style/TabStyle"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When my phone changes orientation to landscape I'm not able to scroll to the bottom of the preference screen it scrolls just a bit and I'm still not able to see my the editextfield on the bottom(see picture - i have another editext field under 640x480 text).

[image: Unable to scrolldown to the very bottom in landscape mode]

My preferences layout looks like that:

```
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 ...
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="picture1"
        android:key="editTextPref"
        android:summary="picture"
        android:title="picture" />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```